# First write code using API, then actual API - does this approach have a name and is valid for API design process?

Tags: language-agnostic, api-design

Standard way of working on new API (library, class, whatever) usually looks like this:

- you think about what methods would API user need
- you implement API that you suspect user will need

So basically you trying to guess what your API should look like. It very often leads to over engineering stuff, huge APIs that you **think** user will need and it is very possible that great part of your code won't be used at all.

Some time ago, maybe few years even, I read some article that promoted writing client code first. I don't remember where I found it but author pointed out several advantages like better understanding how API will be used, what it should provide and what is basically obsolete. I think idea was that it goes along with SCRUM methodology and user stories but on implementation level.

Just out of curiosity for my latest private project I started not with actual API (some kind of toolkit library) but with client code that would use this API. Of course my code is all in red because classes, methods and properties does not exist and I can forget about help from intellisense but what I noticed is that after few days of coding my application "has" all basic functionalities and my library API "is" a lot smaller than I imagined when starting a project.

I don't say that if somebody took my library and started using it it wouldn't lack some features but I think it helped me to realize that my idea of this API was somewhat flawed because I usually try to cover all bases and provide methods "just in case". And sometimes it bites me badly because I made some stupid mistake in basic functions being more focused on code that somebody maybe would need.

So what I would like to ask you do you ever tried this approach when needed to create a new API and did it helped you? Is it some recognized technique that has a name?

Comment: It never occurred to me *not* to write client code first. How else would you know *anything* about how the library is to be used?

Comment: @Jon - well, I always think something like "I need method that returns list of X filtered by list of Y" and write that method and then use it where it is needed to be called. small difference but quite shifting a point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **So basically you're trying to guess what your API should look like.**

And that's the biggest problem with designing anything this way: there should be no (well, minimal) guesswork in software design. Designing an API based on *assumptions* rather than actual *information* is dangerous, for several reasons:

- It's *directly* counter to the principle of YAGNI: in order to get anything done, you *have* to assume what the user is going to need, with no information to back up those assumptions.
- When you're done, and you finally get around to using your API, you'll invariably find that it sucks to use (poor user experience), because you weren't thinking about *how the library is used* (UX), you were thinking about *what the library must do* (features).
- An API, by definition, is an *interface* for users (i.e., developers). Designing as anything else just makes for a bad design, without fail.

Writing sample code is like designing a GUI before writing the backend: a Good Thing. It forces you to think about user experience and *practical* effects of design decisions without getting bogged down in useless theorising and assumption.

And contrary to Gabriel's answer, this is not bottom-up design: it's top-down. Rather than design the concrete backend of your library and then force an abstract interface on top of it, you *first* design the interface and then worry about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the idea of designing the concrete first and abstracting from that afterwards is called bottom-up design. Test Driven Development uses similar principle to what you describe to support better design. Firstly you write a test, which is an use of code you are going to write afterwards. It is important to proceed stepwise, because you have to proove the API is implementable. IMportant part of each part is refactoring - this allows you design more concise API and reuse parts of your code.

Comment: now, when I think about it this article I mentioned could be about TDD. eh, sometimes you just need somebody to open your eyes on what is hidden in plain sight :)